# Get the capturing group of all iterations

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on C# Regex.

Input text:

```
headera
aa1aaa
aa2aaa
aa3aaa

headerb
aa4aaa
aa5aaa
aa6aaa

headerc
aa7aaa
aa8aaa
aa9aaa
```

I would like to capture the numbers 4, 5, and 6 only which are between *headerb* and *headerc*

My attempts:

I was able to capture those under headera and headerb with pattern below. I cannot apply the same concept on lookbehind since this should be zero-width thus quantifiers are not allowed.

```
aa(\d+)aaa(?=[\s|\S]*headerc)
```

Repeating the capturing group will only capture the last iteration. I cannot apply some wild card regex for the multiple instances.

Please assist.
Thanks

[SOLVED]
Using the advantage of .Net being able to support variable-width look behind.
You may use the patterns below:

```
@"(?<=headerb[\s|\S]*)aa(\d)aaa(?=[\s\S]*headerc)"
@"(?s)(?<=\bheaderb\b.*?)\d+(?=.*?\bheaderc\b)"
@"(?<=\bheaderb\b(?:(?!\bheaderc\b)[\s\S])*)aa(\d+)aaa"
```

Comment: I would recommend first filtering out the lines between `headerb` and `headerc`, then applying a regex to these select lines.

Comment: I believe you can use [`(?:headerb|(?!^)\G)\D*(\d+)\D*(?=.*headerc)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3aheaderb%7c(%3f!%5e)%5cG)%5cD*(%5cd%2b)%5cD*(%3f%3d.*headerc)&i=headera%0d%0aaa1aaa%0d%0aaa2aaa%0d%0aaa3aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderb%0d%0aaa4aaa%0d%0aaa5aaa%0d%0aaa6aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderc%0d%0aaa7aaa%0d%0aaa8aaa%0d%0aaa9aaa&o=s), but this might be an inefficient solution. A similar one: [`(?s)(?<=\bheaderb\b.*?)\d+(?=.*?headerc)`](http://goo.gl/9NXp9h). As for *quantifiers are not allowed* - in .NET regex, lookbehinds are variable-width.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: .NET regular expressions store information about [every capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) of group not only last one.

Comment: Please mark the answer as answer and don't change the title to `SOLVED`...

Answer (score 4):

C# supports variable lookbehind.So use it.

```
(?<=\bheaderb\b(?:(?!\bheaderc\b)[\s\S])*)aa(\d+)aaa
```

[See Demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5Cbheaderb%5Cb(%3F%3A(%3F!%5Cbheaderc%5Cb)%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D)*)aa(%5Cd%2B)aaa&i=headera%0D%0Aaa1aaa%0D%0Aaa2aaa%0D%0Aaa3aaa%0D%0A%0D%0Aheaderb%0D%0Aaa4aaa%0D%0Aaa5aaa%0D%0Aaa6aaa%0D%0A%0D%0Aheaderc%0D%0Aaa7aaa%0D%0Aaa8aaa%0D%0Aaa9aaa)

Comment: worked. I didn't know .Net supports variable lookbehind.

Comment: @DracoSahin now you know :)

Comment: already upvote the answer :) Online regex tools won't allow it. Not knowing .Net allows it @-@

Comment: @DracoSahin Upvoting is diff.you need to click the green arrow

Answer (score 2):

You regex does not match what you need because it does not include the boundaries. Note `aa(\d+)aaa(?=[\s|\S]*headerc)` matches `aa`, followed by 1 or more digits that are followed by any character (`[\s\S]` is the same as `[\s|\S]`), 0 or more occurrences, followed by `headerc`. Thus, you do not have a *leading* boundary.

If you insist on a regex, you can make use of a *variable-width* lookbehind in .NET regex:

```
(?s)(?<=\bheaderb\b(?>(?!\bheader[bc]\b).)*)\d+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cbheaderb%5cb(%3f%3e(%3f!%5cbheader%5bbc%5d%5cb).)*)%5cd%2b&i=headera%0d%0aaa1aaa%0d%0aaa2aaa%0d%0aaa3aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderb%0d%0aaa4aaa%0d%0aaa5aaa%0d%0aaa6aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderc%0d%0aaa7aaa%0d%0aaa8aaa%0d%0aaa9aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderb%0d%0aaa4aaa%0d%0aaa5aaa%0d%0aaa6aaa%0d%0a%0d%0aheaderc&o=s). The `(?<=\bheaderb\b(?>(?!\bheader[bc]\b).)*)` lookbehind makes sure there is a whole word `headerb` or `headerc` and some 0 or more characters as few as possible before a sequence of digits (note the Singleline modifier I added to force the `.` to match a newline). The `(?>(?!\bheader[bc]\b).)*` is a [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) that matches any substring that does not contain either `headerc` or `headerb` as whole words. It is necessary in case there is another `headerb....headerc` block after `headerc...headerd` (see my regex demo).

However, the regex solution is not efficient (though potenatially a "quick and dirty" one-time solution). You can also use this trick: split the input with newline symbols into a list of "lines", find the block you need with LINQ, and then apply a simple regex to find all digit sequences:

```
var lines = s.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Split into line array
var subset = lines.SkipWhile(p => p != "headerb") // Get to the "headerb" line
                  .Skip(1)    // Get to the line after "headerb"
                  .TakeWhile(m => m != "headerc")  // Grab the lines in the block we need
                  .ToList();
var digits = Regex.Matches(string.Join(string.Empty, subset), "[0-9]+")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(v => v.Value)
                 .ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: used pattern below. It worked.
(?s)(?<=\bheaderb\b.*?)\d+(?=.*?\bheaderc\b)

Note that using Regex.Matches(), you may acquire the value at match.Groups[0]. Since look aheads and look behind were used, the exact match (4, 5, 6) we're the ones only captured.

Comment: Yes, you may use it like `var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?s)(?<=\bheaderb\b.*?)\d+(?=.*?\bheaderc\b)").Cast<Match>().Select(v => v.Value).ToList();`. You may get any captured substrings with `Match.Groups[n].Value` where *n* is the number or name of a capturing group, too. In this regex, there are no capturing groups at all, thus `Match.Groups[0].Value` can simply be replaced with `Match.Value`

Comment: @DracoSahin: There are .NET-compatible online regex testers: [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) (I used it in my answer), [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester), and there are some others less known. A free tool can be used that also explains subpatterns and generates .NET code - [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend simplifying the problem and use regex only per line processing in such case, after pre-selecting the right lines first.

Anyway, for this particular example something as simple as:

```
headerb\n(aa(\d+)aaa\n)+\nheaderc
```

should work. You might need to adjust the whitespaces / line feeds. Just grab the number from the (\d+) group.
P.S. you cna use named  groups for convenience, ex. 
`(?<number>\d+)` will create the `number` group.

More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What about that regex:

[`(?<=headerb)[\r\n]*(?:aa(?<number>\d+)aaa[\r\n]*)+(?=headerc)`](http://goo.gl/6cNCps)

[Code sample](http://ideone.com/Kc09HL)

It prints out exactly what you want (4, 5, 6).

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=headerb)[\r\n]*(?:aa(?<number>\d+)aaa[\r\n]*)+(?=headerc)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var match = regex.Match(<input>);
if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (var number in match.Groups["number"].Captures.Cast<Capture>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```